# Show get updates every second on a NSTimer whose interval isn't 1

Tags: ios, timer, synchronization, nstimer

I'm trying to create a label that shows the time on a NSTimer, however my problem is that the interval on the timer isn't 1.0 and so there is no way to update the label every second like I would like to be able to. I have tried to synchronize two timers, however that is proving to be a challenge. So, Is there a way to get secondary updates or synchronize two timers of different interval?

Comment: >>" the interval on the timer isn't 1.0" ???

Comment: yes the interval is 5 seconds, as in the selector it is assigned to is called every five seconds.

Comment: Then why don't you set the interval to 1 second instead of to 5? I really don't understand what the problem is or what the question is. I think you will have to show some code to explain what the problem is, its just not explained well at all at the moment.

Comment: I need the timer to call a method every five seconds, and so I can't just change it!! but using the same timer, I need it to call another method every one second, or synchronize two timers but with different intervals

Comment: Don't get in a huff. Now I don't feel included to be bothered to help you. Good luck. P.S. Ask better and clearer questions in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reading your question as follows:

I have a timer that needs to fire once per 5 seconds, but I would like to tell the user how many seconds remain until the timer fires.

The simplest way that I can think of is to make an intermediary method that the first timer will call.  You would change:

timer -> METHOD_A

to

timer -> METHOD_B -> METHOD_A

the timer could then be set to update every .1 seconds, and METHOD_B could keep track of the time and just call METHOD_A when 5 seconds have passed since the previous call.

For what it's worth though I don't think that NSTimer will slip, so when you are updating the time you are probably doing something like time=time+interval, where it might make more sense to do (currentTime-startingTime)%interval, and then the synchronization shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Thank you! thats what I was missing.